# Unity3D - Which network solution to choose?

Tags: c#, .net, networking, unity-game-engine

For a small-sized company I'm going over all possible network solutions to see which one would be best for our Unity games to come. So far I've seen come across the following options:

- Unity networking
- Photon Cloud
- TNet
- UnityPark Suite (uLink)
- SmartFoxServer

I would like to hear everybody's experience with the products above:

- Was it easy to implement?
- How was the support?
- How well is it documented?
- How well is it maintained?
- Were there any issues with the connectivity?
- What are the general pros and cons?
- For what kind of games did you use it?

I know the best solution often depends on the concerned project. However as a company, going with one network solution for all games can save a lot of time on the learning of new products.

Comment: @MikePennington Yes, C#

Comment: Could you at least mention what genre(s) you're developing? Because a turn-based game and an FPS would have very different needs from their networking library. Like SmartFox would be fine for a Habbo Hotel game, but not for Counterstrike.

Comment: I recommand Forge Networking Remastered

Answer (score 3):

While I haven't used any networking libraries with unity3d or games, I've used [Lidgren](http://code.google.com/p/lidgren-network-gen3/) for a project, which (from what I've read) is used for game networking, and can be used with unity3d. I found it quite easy to use and customize to suit my needs, and haven't come up with any serious connectivity issues with it. Of course this being an open source library it may not be what you're looking for, but I just thought I'd point it out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, Lidgren isn't specialized to Unity. We are looking for a more specialized solution, to avoid reinventing the wheel (and probably reinvent it worse).

Comment: AI War: Fleet Command is a Unity game that shipped using Lidgren as its networking library. So even though it isn't advertised as a Unity lib it could be worth evaluating.

Answer (score 3):

I've used the Photon Cloud and Network Unity ...

Implementation of the two is very similar and easy to use.
Is well documented, the two.
I'm using them, both for FPS style games.
The style of play is heavy, 3D models, many particles.

Photon Cloud: In game FPS style have lag, however, only used the free version, perhaps with the paid version is better.

Link: http://doc.exitgames.com/photon-cloud/PUNOverview/#cat-tutorials

Unity Network: I did not use external servers, and worked well, but with a few players ... with many for quite some lag.

Link: http://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Manual/NetworkedMultiplayer.html

I recommend these two, but depending on the complexity of the game may need to invest money on servers or paid plans.

If you have server external, I recommend Network Unity, otherwise I recommend Photon Clound.

But I think for less complex games free version will serve well.

Hope this helps!